# List View not updating correctly on state change

Tags: react-native

I have been using list view in my application. It does not update the state of individual rows once I have changed their property. I am doing it like this:

```
rowData.showMenuDiv = !rowData.showMenuDiv;
this.setState({ dataSource : this.state.dataSource });
```

But only the first row responds correctly and the rest are not updated correctly. I have also tried making a new array and assigning it like:

```
rowData.showMenuDiv = !rowData.showMenuDiv;
var newArray = oldDataArray.splice()
this.setState({ dataSource : dataSource.cloneWithRows(newArray) });
```

But this didn't work at all.

The only solution that is working, is by creating a new data source and assigning it the updated array
like:

```
rowData.showMenuDiv = !rowData.showMenuDiv;
var dataSource = new ListView.DataSource
( {rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => ( r1.showMenuDiv != r2.showMenuDiv )});
this.setState({ dataSource : dataSource.cloneWithRows(oldDataArray) });
```

Please explain if I am doing any thing wrong in the top two methods. Or the method I am using to update rows is correct (the last method)?

Comment: Does `this.state.dataSource` reflect your changes when you're doing `rowData.showMenuDiv = !rowData.showMenuDiv;`? Most likely not which is why you're not seeing the changes.

Comment: It does reflect the changes. The variable is updated.